# Upgrading From Shimano 8 Sp Alivio To Shimano 9 Sp Altus

Tags: cassette, commuting-bike

I have an old giant warp D's 2 bike that's about 10 years old. I've maintained it and it still rides good and looks just as good. I wanted to upgrade from the old alivio 8 speed drivetrain to either a new alivio or altus 9 speed ddrivetrain but wasn't sure if the cassette would fit on the freehub on the bike and I didn't want to buy the components and then found out they couldn't fit and then be stuck with useless parts. Could somebody please help the old man stuck in a rut?

Comment: Why 9 speed? You can still get good 8 speed shifters and its not like the extra speed will help.

Comment: I Actually Want To Go To 9 Speed For The Summer When I Go On Vacation To Pennsylvania

Comment: I still don't see how the extra cog in the back is going to help -- you're better off picking up a well chosen 8 speed cassette, especially on a commuter.

Comment: A 9s cassette will fit with to a 8s freehub. You also don't really need to replace the crankset although it would improve the culture of shifting.

Comment: Hello Batman. I Was Wondering If You Could Help Me ???? Would You Happen To Know If The 9 Speed Shimano Crank And Cassette Might Fit On My Giant Warp DS 2 ??? I Actually Was Going To Overhaul The Entire Drive train If I Could Go Up To A 9 Speed From An 8 Speed.

Comment: Oh Sorry I Forgot Its A 2005 Model

Comment: @Slovakov Hello I'm new here so I'm not familiar with how things are done so please forgive my ignorance. What I wanted to know specifically is if the 9 Speed cassette would fit between the hub and bike where the wheel connects I guess it might be called an arm I guess I'm not sure what its called but I wasn't sure if it might be to wide or to high/ thick to replace an 8 speed cassette

Comment: This thing is called a freehub and it's a part of a hub. You put a cassette on it and lock it with a lockring. There is a single standard freehub width compatible with practically all 8, 9 and 10s cassetes. An older solution is a freewheel, and is a thing which is screwed on a hub, but these are usually used in very cheap bikes and mainly exist as 6 or 7s sets. There are some 8s freewheels, but they are quite rare these days.

Answer (score 1):

A 9 speed cassette will fit on an 8 speed hub. The extra gear is accommodated using thinner cogs and spacers.  You will also need a new shifter as its the shifter that provides the indexing for the gears. If you also increase the range of gears (increase the largest cassette cog), you may need a new rear deraileur.

Its possible to run 8 speed chain rings with a 9 speed chain, but you will get better shifting upgrading the chain-rings. In this case, replacing the entire crank set might be cheaper.

There would be little advantage replacing the deraileurs (especially the front) unless they are worn out.